# Java: Program stopping for ~1s occasionally with JavaSound

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm getting some weird behavior from JavaSound in Java 8 in which I have a Sound class and randomly (every 3-5 instances or so) when being created the thread halts for 0-2s

This is constructor method

```
public Sound(String fileName) {
    // specify the sound to play
    // (assuming the sound can be played by the audio system)
    // from a wave File
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
         // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sound);
            length = clip.getMicrosecondLength();
            System.out.println("length: " + length);
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: file not found: " + fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: " + e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: " + e);
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

My current thoughts are either it is having issues allocating memory(seeing as there are multiple of these instances in an ArrayList), the file is taking long to open from as the coding isn't ideal or it's having trouble removing the objects.

Here's the ArrayList code just in case

```
public static void playSound(String file){
    sounds.add(new Sound("res/" + file));
    Sound sound = sounds.get(sounds.size()-1);
    sound.setVolume(Screen.music.getVolume());
    sound.play();
}
```

I've tried running the above section of code in a new thread and the main thread continues but the sounds don't always play.

Edit: I do have some sort of garbage collection to clear up most of the memory for the Sound objects but I don't think the problem is related to that, however reusing the objects might be a valid idea?

```
public void checkStatus(){
        if(clip.getMicrosecondPosition() >= length){
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    clip.stop();
                    clip.close();
                    clip.flush();
                    clip.drain();
                    Screen.sounds.remove(this);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Garbage collection? Are you creating and discarding a lot of objects? Could they be reused instead?

Comment: Good idea but I'm not quite sure how to do that? Any links or a direction to get started on with that?

And yes definitely creating and discarding lots of objects throughout the program but the sound stuff is really taking its toll

Comment: I mean the pause is due to garbage collection.

Comment: Oh, could be, I have no idea how I would go about fixing that though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long GC pauses in application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696585/long-gc-pauses-in-application)

Comment: Yeah it seems to be, I'll take a closer look at the question you linked and I'll take a closer look at my own code, even knowing what direction to look at for a fix is a great help!